# Openshift redirect to https on Node

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, openshift

I am building a Node.js application hosted on OpenShift. I am trying to redirect all visits to the https version of the website.

I tried adding an .htaccess file in the public directory as it was suggested in some other posts but it does not make a difference.

below is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I use AngularJs and ui-router for handling navigation on the website. By implementing the code below I am able to achieve the redirection to https but I think this should be handled on the server side.

```
if(window.location.protocol != 'https'){
        $window.location.href = $location.absUrl().replace('http', 'https');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The .HTACCESS can be used with Apache based cartridges. Check [this FAQ answer](https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_how_do_i_redirect_traffic_to_https); it describes how to redirect to HTTPS with Express.</del>

**Edit:**

The original answer addressed the question for OpenShift Online v2, which is [no longer available](https://blog.openshift.com/migrate-to-v3-v2-eol/). When hosting an app on OpenShift 3, creating a [secure route](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/networking/routes.html#secured-routes) with the `insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy` set to `Redirect` would handle the redirect on platform level, without a need to address this in the application itself.

---

When using certain [OpenShift Online 3](https://www.openshift.com/products/online/) subscription plans (that would be the *Starter* plan, at time of writing this edit), routes could be [restricted](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/routes.html#custom-route-and-hosts-and-certificates-restrictions) to default hosts and certificates.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Link is dead, and future people looking to solve this are sad.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **express.js** in your node application you can use `req.secure` to check if the request comes through `https`. ([reference](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.secure)).

So you can write middleware that you can add to all your routes that will check if the request comes through `https` and re-route if it comes through `http`.

For example:

**https-redirect.js** file:

```
exports.httpsRedirect = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.secure) {
    next();
  }
  else {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.path);
  }
};
```

---

**app.js** file (or whatever you use to define routes):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var https = require('./https-redirect');

app.all('*', https.httpsRedirect);
```

---

Now all your routes will run the `https.httpsRedirect` middleware first and re-route to `https` if necessary.